# How to access Session Timeout Value in web.xml?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, webserver, session-timeout

I want to implement idle session Timeout on the server-side in my web application. I'm using the Tomcat server.

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

I can able to create an idle Session Timeout of 10 minutes but I also want to notify users if the timer is going to expire.
Example: If only 2 minutes remaining in Timer, then I'll create a modal window displaying "Your session is going to expire, press ok to continue your session"

For those activities, I need to access and modify the session Timeout value.

My question is,

1. Is it possible to access the session configuration?
2. If yes, how to access it?
3. If no, what are the other ways to perform these actions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the configured timeout from the session itself, use [getMaxInactiveInterval](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval--). It gives you the time in seconds.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, Also
Is there any way to,
1. Get the remaining Time left
Ex: If I configured the Timeout to be 15 minutes, I need to get notified when the timer reaches 10 minutes. Any idea on this?
2. **Is it possible to reset that timer?**

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it was correct. You can calculate the remaining time using getLastAccessedTime. The timer is automatically reset on every access, so simply trigger a web request from the client. There is no good way to get notified. The normal approach is to do this in the browser instead with JavaScript. You need to be client side anyway to display your window. In fact the JavaScript can have its own shorter timer and ignore the server setting. As long as the client times out before the server the server timeout is irrelevant.